# Android app- custom dialog is not working when clicked from a button in titlebar

Tags: android, dialog, android-titlebar

In my app I have 3 buttons on title bar, rest two works fine, third one should generate a dialog box. But if fails at this line-dialogabt.setContentView(R.layout.custom);

[Screenshot of titlebar][1]

Here is relevant code(Please let me know if I should post more code)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_inc) {
        incsize(rl);
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_dec) {
        decsize(rl);
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_abt) {  
  dialogabt = new Dialog(ActivityName.this);
            dialogabt.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialogabt.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialogabt.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

R.menu.main

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
android:id="@+id/action_dec"
android:icon="@drawable/search_minus"
android:title="dec"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/action_inc"
android:icon="@drawable/search_plusn"
android:title="inc"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/action_abt"
android:icon="@drawable/info"
android:title="info"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Here is error log-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:471)
at dhritiapps.tulsiramayan.ActivityName.onOptionsItemSelected(ActivityName.java:423)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:412)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:188)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:202)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:761)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:947)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:153)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:471)
at dhritiapps.tulsiramayan.ActivityName.onOptionsItemSelected(ActivityName.java:423)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:412)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:188)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:202)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:761)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:947)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:153)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020056 a=-1 r=0x7f020056}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1927)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:471)
at dhritiapps.tulsiramayan.ActivityName.onOptionsItemSelected(ActivityName.java:423)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:412)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:188)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:202)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:761)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:947)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:153)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_alert2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_header"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="About this App"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:padding="10dp"
         /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

And below is custom_alert2.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#235685" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners
        android:radius="8dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: post your custom.xml layout

Comment: post your custom.xml layout

Comment: You guys are right, Problem is in custom.xml, I have added this file. On further analysis it turned out that if I use same custom.xml without background, its working fine. But once I add background<android:background="@drawable/custom_alert2">, Then this problem occurs. Any idea, how to resolve it. I need background to custom.xml.

Comment: @MohitSuthar Please help. I have posted custom.xml and some more information on it

Comment: @Naitik Please help. I have posted custom.xml and some more information on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that extends the dialog and implements onClickListener.

Here is an example code.

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

  public Activity c;
  public Dialog d;
  public Button yes, no;

  public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
    no.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_yes:
      c.finish();
      break;
    case R.id.btn_no:
      dismiss();
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    dismiss();
  }
}
```

**How to Call Dialog ?**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_inc) {
        incsize(rl);
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_dec) {
        decsize(rl);
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_abt) {  
            CustomDialogClass dlg = new CustomDialogClass(Balkand.this);
            dlg.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If this does not work, I need to check out the xml for custom dialog. 
Can you post here it?

Comment: This doesn't work. Again same error now from new class of same line.

Comment: Added custom.xml. An update is that when I use this custom.xml after removing background(android:background="@drawable/custom_alert2") from it, everything works fine. Please analyze and help.

Comment: Anyone please help, I have tried everything, But not able to set background to my custom dialog.

Comment: @PankajBhardwaj let me try tonight